# Mysterious text/html request appears in the network tab

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, google-chrome, jwt

I have set up JWT verification in my project (Express + React).

**verifyJWT.ts**

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

interface IRequest extends Request {
  userId: string;
}

export const verifyJWT = (req: IRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

  if (!authHeader) {
    return res.status(401).send('No token provided');
  }
  const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET as string, (err, decoded: any) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
    req.userId = decoded?.id;
    next();
  });
};
```

**server.ts**

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(helmet());

app.use('/register', registerRouter);
app.use('/login', loginRouter);
app.use('/refresh-token', refreshTokenRouter);

app.use(verifyJWT as any);

app.get('/test', (req: Request, res: Response) =>
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Hello from test!' }),
);
```

**client test.tsx**

```
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { axiosInstance } from '@utils/axios-instance';

export const Test = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(['stupid query key'], () => axiosInstance.get('/test'), {
    cacheTime: 0,
    staleTime: 0,
  });

  const message = data?.data.message ? data?.data.message : 'no data';

  return <h1>{message}</h1>;
};
```

**client login.tsx**

```
import { useMutation } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { LoginUser, loginUserAction } from './login-user.action';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { AxiosError } from 'axios';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import { tokenStorage } from '@utils/token-storage';
import useUserAccount from '@utils/hooks/use-user-account';
import { setMetadata, startLogin, finishLogin } from '@context/user/user-account.actions';

const validationSchema = yup
  .object({
    username: yup
      .string()
      .required('Username is required')
      .min(6, 'Username must be at least 6 characters')
      .max(20, 'Username must be at most 50 characters')
      .trim(),

    password: yup
      .string()
      .trim()
      .min(8, 'Passowrd must be at least 8 characters')
      .max(50, 'Passowrd must be at most 50 characters')
      .required('Password is required'),
  })
  .required();

export const Login = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setError,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<LoginUser>({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
  });
  const { state } = useLocation();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { dispatch } = useUserAccount();

  const { mutate } = useMutation(loginUserAction, {
    onSuccess: (response) => {
      dispatch(startLogin());

      if (!response) return;

      const { accessToken, username, email } = response.data;

      // const user = jwt.decode(accessToken) as { id: string; exp: number };
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
      const decoded = jwtDecode(accessToken) as { id: string; exp: number };

      tokenStorage.setAccessToken(accessToken, decoded.exp);

      dispatch(setMetadata({ username, email }));
      dispatch(finishLogin());
      navigate('/');
    },
    onError: (err: AxiosError) => {
      if (err.response?.data) {
        setError('root.serverError', {
          type: 'serverError',
          message: err.response.data as string,
        });
      }
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: LoginUser) => {
    mutate({ username: data.username, password: data.password });
  };

  const serverError = errors.root?.serverError?.message;

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center flex-col">
      {state?.registered && (
        <p className="text-green-500 text-2xl mb-4">You have been registered!</p>
      )}
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold text-white mb-5">LOGIN PAGE</h1>
      <form
        className="width-[600px] flex flex-col items-center justify-center"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      >
        <input
          {...register('username')}
          placeholder="login"
          className="mb-2 width-[150px] p-1 rounded-lg outline-none"
        />
        <p className="text-red-500 relative bottom-2">{errors.username?.message}</p>
        <input
          {...register('password')}
          type="password"
          placeholder="password"
          className="width-[150px] p-1 rounded-lg outline-none mb-2"
        />
        <p className="text-red-500 relative bottom-2">{errors.password?.message}</p>
        <button type="submit" className="bg-white w-[100px] mt-4 p-1 rounded-md hover:bg-slate-300">
          OK
        </button>
        {errors.root?.serverError ? (
          <p className="text-red-500 mt-2 text-xl">{serverError}</p>
        ) : null}
        <p className="mt-4 text-white">
          Don't have an account?{' '}
          <Link to="/register" className="underline">
            Register
          </Link>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

However, I am annoyed by the fact that when I try to go to React Route */test* I get the *text/html* 401 request with the error from *verifyJWT*. Even better, it also appears when trying to switch to route */login*, where no query to the server is initiated at the start. I checked in Safari and Firefox, this request is not there.

[image: Network tab]

[image: Network tab]

Why does the browser perform the /test html request to localhost:3000 (browser)?

[image: Network tab]

I receive correct data from the /test endpoint

[image: Network tab]